# In rails.vim why do I get "E345 can't find file in path" errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, rails.vim

I've been learning Ruby/Rails with vim.  Tim Pope's [rails.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails) seems like a really good tool to traverse files with, but I keep getting these pesky "E345 can't find file in path" errors.  I'm not vim expert yet, so the solution isn't obvious.  Additionally, I've tried [this](http://gabebw.wordpress.com/2010/08/03/rails-vim-and-those-pesky-e345-cant-find-file-xxx-in-path-errors/) and it doesn't apply to my problem.

As an example of the problem.  I have a method format_name defined in app/helpers/application_helper.rb and it is used in app/helpers/messages_helper.rb.  Within the latter file I put my cursor over the usage of format_name and then hit gf and I get that error.  Similar disfunction with commands like ]f and [f

However, it works sometimes.  I was able to gf from `user` to the app/models/user.rb

Ideas?

Comment: What version of Vim are you using? What exact commands are you using that are prompting the errors (e.g. “`gf` while cursor is on foo_bar”, “`:Rfind FooBar`”, etc.)? What pathnames from your project do you expect the command(s) to find?

Comment: @Chris - see revised question.  I don't know how to show what files are directories are included on my vim path, this would be helpful.

Comment: You can (usually) examine the value of the `path` option with `:set path?`, but `rails.vim` tends to put a *lot* of entries in there and that command seems to show a truncated result. `:echo &path` should show the whole value, unwieldy though it may be (it has entries for installed gems, which can really add up, but it also means you can jump to the source for (e.g.) `ActiveRecord::Base`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is a limitation of `rails.vim`. It does not support “finding” bare methods. Supporting something like that would require one of the following:

- an exhaustive search of all the source files for each “find” request
  (which could be expensive with large projects),
- “dumb” indexing of method names
  (e.g. Exuberant Ctags and `g`<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd>; see [`:help g_CTRL-]`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/tagsrch.txt.html#g_CTRL-%5D)), or
- smart enough parsing of the code to make a good guess where the method might be defined
  (which is hard to do properly).

If you know where the method is, you can extend many of the navigation commands with a method name:

```
:Rhelper application#format_name
```

But, you do not have to type all of that in. Assuming the cursor is on `format_name` you can probably just type`:Rh`<kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>space</kbd>`app`<kbd>Tab</kbd>`#`<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> (see [:help c_CTRL-R_CTRL-W](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-R_CTRL-W)).

Comment: This seems helpful, although it's going to be a couple days before I can get around to checking.